# как правильно поменять значение в подмассиве массива объектов?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Здрвствуйте, есть вот такой массив объектов:

```
const briefingType = [
    { type: 'elevation',
            users: [
                {userid : '1', userName: 'vasia', date: 'thursday'},
                {userid: '2' ,userName: 'ivan', date: 'monday'},
                {userid: '3' ,userName: 'petro', date: 'false'},

            ] 
    }
    , 
    {type: 'tools', 
            users: [
              {userid : '1', userName: 'vasia', date: 'sunday'},
              {userid: '2' , userName: 'ivan', date: 'false'},
              {userid: '3' , userName: 'petro', date: 'monday'},
            ]  
    },
    {type: 'drugs', 
            users: [
              {userid : '1',userName: 'vasia', date: 'false'},
              {userid: '2' ,userName: 'ivan', date: 'false'},
              {userid: '3' ,userName: 'petro', date: 'monday'},
            ] 
    }
]
```

нужна функция по замене даты для определенного пользователя в определенном типе(например поменять для типа "drags" пользователю vasia установить date: 'friday')

```
const addBriedingDate = function(briefingType, type, userName, date){
for(let key in briefingType){
  if(key.hasOwnProperty('type')=== "drugs"){
    /////?????????????
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const addBriedingDate = function(briefingType, type, userName, date) {
  briefingType.find((e)=>e.type === type).users.find((u)=>u.userName === userName).date = date;
  }
```

и не забудьте поменять объявление массива на let

```
let briefingType = [
    { type: 'elevation',
            users: [
...
```